# Simple MySQL Query does not running on server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have written a very simple query

```
UPDATE product_variants SET remaining= 15 WHERE id=(select id where remaining<15)
```

which is doing its work successfully on my local machine.

However, the same query is giving following error on server

> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where
>   remaining<15)' at line 1

I know that same query can also be written as

```
UPDATE `product_variants` SET `remaining`= 15 WHERE remaining<15;
```

but I want to know the syntax error in the first query.

mysql --version

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.52, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Ubuntu version

> Linux ip-172-31-27-247 3.13.0-74-generic #118-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:52:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: What's your result when you do just this on the server that doesn't work? select id where remaining<15

Comment: It shows my all ids whose remaining is less than 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use same update table in select statement in subquery , you can find the reason in this link: [Reason for not use same table in sub-query.](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/)

try below query:

```
 SET @r_ids = (select GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM product_variants where remaining <15); 
     /* set the result id's into the one variable. */
 SELECT @r_ids;
     /* If you want to check the variable value, use above statement. */
 UPDATE product_variants SET remaining= 15 
 WHERE id IN (@r_ids); 
    /* update that same id's which is find into the @r_ids. */
```

You can find more about variable here in this link.[More about Variables.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

First of all store the id's into the some variable and then update those id's using `in` query.

Comment: Yes same error `MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where remaining<15)' at line 1`

Comment: The query works but explanation is  required for accepting the answer.

Comment: @Cybersupernova , now you can understand this? or need more explanation?

Comment: I already understood the query, but the thing I do not get is why it is working with variable and not with sub query.

Comment: and also it is working on local system but not on server

Comment: @Cybersupernova , check the upated link.

Comment: It's very thankful you are providing so much rich resources but I am searching the reason for `MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where remaining<15)' at line 1` this error

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE product_variants SET remaining= 15 WHERE id=(select id where remaining<15)`

Two thinks:

1. `(select GROUP_CONCAT(id) where remaining<15)` is missing the table you want to select from `SELECT id FROM ... where remaining<15`
2. You have to use `where id in` instead of `where id =` since your query might return multiple rows.

this should work:

```
UPDATE product_variants
SET remaining= 15
WHERE id IN
        (SELECT id
         FROM
             (SELECT id
              FROM product_variants
              WHERE remaining<15) a)
```

Comment: *Exactly* the same?

Comment: Does it throw the same error when you execute only the inner part?
`SELECT id
         FROM product_variants
         WHERE remaining<15`

Comment: No it provides me the accurate results

Comment: Well I get another error:
`ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'product_variants' for update in FROM clause`

But anyway. The second solution is much better anyway! Stick with the second one.

Comment: Surely, it is a better option but this question is focused on why mysql is throwing error for the first query.

Comment: That's the strange thing since I'm receiving another error than you.
Why the first one fails I already pointed out in my answer.

Comment: I am searching the reason for `MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where remaining<15)' at line 1` this error. I am aware of same table can not be used in sub query

Comment: Because there is a syntax error in your first query!
`select id where remaining<15` It says there is a syntax error near `where remaining<15`. The syntax error occurs because mysql expects `FROM table_name` instead of `where remaining`. I hope this answers your question.